# marker.setMap(null); does not work

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I want to remove all old marker from google map and add new one but setMap(null) does not work and it add new marker without remove old one . Please look into my code

```
                var markers = data['map'];
                if (marker != null) {
                    marker.setMap(null);
                }
                marker.setMap(null);
                for (var i = 0; i < markers.length; i++) {
                    alert(1);
                    var data = markers[i];
                    var infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
                    var img1 = data.imageUrl != '' ? '<img src= <?php echo $baseUrl; ?>/uploads/property/thumb/' + data.imageUrl + '>' : "";

                    var bed1 = data.beds != '' ? data.beds + ' beds' : "";
                    var bath1 = data.bath != '' ? data.bath + ' bath' : "";
                    var squarefeet1 = data.areaSqaureFeet != '' ? data.areaSqaureFeet + ' squarefeet' : "";
                    var contentString = '<div id="content">';
                    contentString += img1+ '<p>' + data.propertyAddress + ' </p><p> ' + bed1 + '   </p><p>' + bath1 + ' </p><p>' + squarefeet1 + '  </p>';
                    contentString += '</div>';

                    var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(data.lat, data.lng);
                    marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                        position: myLatlng,
                        map: map,
                        title: contentString
                    });

                    google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
                        infowindow.setContent(this.title);
                        infowindow.open(map, this);
                    }); 
                } 
            }
```

Answer (score 1):

I don´t see where you defined you "marker" variable. 
However, in general you should create a Marker -> push it into a global defined array (or just an array that you can access) so you have a reference to it. You can then just run over the marker array and set it null. So you could do it this way:

```
var markers = []; //Global Marker array to keep references
 var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: {lat: lat, lng: lng},
        icon: icon,
        map: map
    });
    markers.push(marker);
```

This will keep your markers accessible. If you want to set them null 
you could write a function like this one:

```
removeMarker: function () {
    for (var i = 0; i < markers.length; i++) {
        markers[i].setMap(null);
    }
    markers = [];
},
```

Hope that helped.